# Remove datarow with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable in which I have the index number of the row that i want to delete using linq. I cant seem to get this to work properly because I am writing

```
int RowIndex = 3;  
DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList().RemoveAt(RowIndex);
DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

There is no error but it does not remove the row.

Comment: Your code removes that row from `List<DataRow>` instance that is created by `ToList()` call, not from the `DataTable` itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting specific rows from DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable)

Comment: As a rule, LINQ is for *querying*, not *mutating*.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need LINQ for this.  Just remove it directly:

```
theDataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
theDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```