# Remove rows from datatable matching a List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a DataTable and I want to remove all the rows matching a `List< string>`, how to do that? Following is my code,

```
public static DataTable GetSkills(List<Skill> EnteredSkills)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = GetDBMaster("SkillMaster");
    List<string> MatchingSkills = EnteredSkills.Select(c => c.Text).ToList();
    //Logic to Delete rows MatchingSkills from dt here
    return dt;
}
```

**Final Solution**

```
    public static DataTable GetSkills(List<Skill> EnteredSkills)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = GetDBMaster("SkillMaster");
        var MatchingSkills = new HashSet<string>(EnteredSkills.Select(c => c.Text));
        List<DataRow> removeRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => MatchingSkills.Contains(r.Field<string>("DataTableSkillColumnName"))).ToList();
        removeRows.ForEach(dt.Rows.Remove);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you simply loop and check the matching rows and delete it from the data table ?

Comment: Yes, but is there a better way to do this, there are many such situations in my entire project.

Comment: What is happening inside the method `GetDBMaster()`, why don't you include the `MatchingSkills` as a condition in the query that populates the datatable?

Comment: GetDBMaster gives the skillmaster from a static datatble variable, which is loaded from DB only once when the first user makes a request to my page. So it has complete master, I am trying to filter rows from that master here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming the column is `SkillName`

```
List<DataRow> removeRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => MatchingSkills.Contains(r.Field<string>("SkillName")))
    .ToList();
removeRows.ForEach(dt.Rows.Remove);
```

Side- note: i would use a `HashSet<string>` because it would be more efficient:

```
var MatchingSkills = new HashSet<string>(EnteredSkills.Select(c => c.Text));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way will be:

```
var lstRemoveColumns = new List<string>() { "ColValue1", "ColVal2", "ColValue3", "ColValue4" };
List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    if (lstRemoveColumns.Contains(row["ColumnName"].ToString())) 
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(row);
    }
}

foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete) 
{
    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great! I'm using it for my solution.

```
List<DataRow> lsFilteredData = dtUnfilteredData.AsEnumerable().Where(q => lsWhatIWanted.Contains(q.Field<string>("Code"))).ToList();

foreach (DataRow drFilteredData in lsFilteredData)
{
    //Do whatever you want here
}
```