# Remove a DataRow from a DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a DataSet called `EventDBDataSet` and there is a DataTable called `Contacts` in it. I'm trying to delete a row from the DataTable and it's not working and it does not throw any errors. I tried some of the Stack Overflow solutions regarding this, but none of them worked for me. Following the code for deleting the row from DataTable

```
public void deleteContact(Int16 contactId)
{
    EventDBDataSet eventDBDataSet = new EventDBDataSet();
    EventDBDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsTableAdapter contactsTableAdapter =
        new EventDBDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsTableAdapter();

    contactsTableAdapter.Fill(eventDBDataSet.Contacts);

    EventDBDataSet.ContactsRow contactsRow = eventDBDataSet.Contacts.FindBycontactId(contactId);

    eventDBDataSet.Contacts.RemoveContactsRow(contactsRow);

    eventDBDataSet.Contacts.AcceptChanges();

    contactsTableAdapter.Update(eventDBDataSet.Contacts);

}
```

what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you still need this?

Comment: @RandomStuff yes please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting specific rows from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an item from a collection, that collection has been changed and you can't continue to enumerate through it.

Instead, use a For loop, such as:

```
public void RemoveRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (var row in dt.Select())
        {
            if (row["ID"].ToString().Equals("NAME"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not getting ant error or any output. Datatable not get updated after performing the delete.

Comment: Have updated answer which worked for me, give that a try.

Comment: You sure it worked ?? EventDBDataSet.ContactsRow does not have a method called Select()

Comment: I ensure you it works for me, Select() returns an array of all DataRow objects. Please use the edit I have added this works correctly in VS 2019.

Comment: Have you checked that EventDBDataSet.ContactsRow is of type DataTable?