# DataTable customization with records

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, web-controls

I Have 1 Datatable having 10 rows and ListBox having 8 ListItems contains 6 records from the DataTable and 2 new records.

I want to update the DataTable in such a way that 6 records should be as it is and remove remaining 4 records from DataTable and add 2 newly added entries from ListBox in DataTable.

What I tried is I looped ListBox record from DataTable and created list of matched records.

```cs
string impactedTC;
List<int> index = new List<int>();
// This retruns my dataset having 10 records           
DataTable dttable = GetImpactedTestCaseDetailsToUpdateStatus().Tables[0];

for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int count = 0;

    string dTestCase = ListBox1.Items[i].Text;
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in dttable.Rows)
    {
        impactedTC = dtRow["TestCaseName"].ToString();
        if (impactedTC == dTestCase)
        {
            index.Add(count);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include sample code to give us something to work with.

Comment: @djsoteric i created list of index that are matched with datatable records. now i want to remove rest of the records from datatable.

Comment: You should be able to iterate through the records and delete them in one transaction after you've identified with rows do not belong. I would do it with LINQ instead of writing a loop though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable

Comment: @djsoteric can you update above code with your logic?

Comment: You want to put the statement count++ inside the if statement so it only increments when you match the TestCaseName.

Comment: How can you add 2 newly added entries from list to datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [Ling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

To keep the 6 rows and remove the remaining 4 from the `DataTable`:

```cs
//Assuming the names are DataTable1 and ListBox1.
var rowsToRemove = from r in DataTable1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        where listBox1.Items
        .Cast<ListItem>()
        .Aggregate(0, (n, li) => li.Text.ToLower() == r.Field<string>("TestCaseName").ToLower() ? n + 1 : n) == 0
        select r;
```

To get the new items from the ListBox:

```cs
var newItems = from li in listBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                where DataTable1.Rows
                .Cast<DataRow>()
                .Aggregate(0, (n, r) => r.Field<string>("TestCaseName").ToLower() == li.Text.ToLower() ? n + 1 : n) == 0
                select li;
```

and finally update the DataTable:

```cs
rowsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(r => DataTable1.Rows.Remove(r));
newItems.ToList().ForEach(li => DataTable1.Rows.Add(li.Text)); //or maybe li.Value
```

> **Important**
>
> You might need to replace any `li.Text` with `li.Value` in the preceding code and that depends on how the ListItem objects are created. Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem?view=netframework-4.8) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @JQSOFT I do have ListItem so struggling to to add new item into datatable. Could you please help me in this?

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.IConvertible' error occurred during execution. can you help me in this.

Comment: @prashanatchaudhar Of course it will throw that exception since it is a different type. You had to make your post more clear by adding the right tags, the type of your project,.. etc. Anyway, The same logic will work if you change the types and call the correct properties. Try the edited code,

Comment: @prashanatchaudhar Also check what you are really need to get, is it the [ListItem.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.text?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListItem_Text) property or the [ListItem.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListItem_Value)?

Comment: ListItem.Text is required. I am new to linq i am still struggling with this. Could you please help me with the code? @JQSOFT

Comment: @prashanatchaudhar I Just did mate, check the code. I replaced the `string` with `ListItem`, and I removed the alternative function since it won't work here. Try it and tell me what you get.

Comment: thanks. review view has expected values however adding into DataTable using Li.Text getting 'Input string was not in a correct format.' error  and for li.value i blank values added into DataTable.

Comment: Also i want to ask  rowsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(r => DataTable1.Rows.Remove(r)); rowsToRemove.ToList() i want to remove this from database using my in build function. is there any way to call my function from Linq syntax?

Comment: This is what i tried
foreach(DataRow dr in rowsToRemove.ToList())
            {
                int Count = 0;
                string testcase = dr.Table.Rows[Count]["TestCaseName"].ToString();
    RemoveTCFromDataBase(testcase);
                Count++;
            }